# bootstrap tab on active changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have this tab in bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="feedtab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#atlass" data-toggle="tab">Atlass</a></li>
  <li><a href="#avi" data-toggle="tab">Aviation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#proc" data-toggle="tab">Processing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#it" data-toggle="tab">IT&S</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="atlass"><div id="updates" data-id-type="1"><div class="alert alert-default well" style="background-color: #f1f1f1"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Portal is Initilizing... Please Wait.</div></div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="avi"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">Aviation Feed Will go here.</div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="proc"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">Processing Feed Will go here.</div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="it"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">IT&S Feed will go here.</div></div>
</div>
```

How do i have an event or soemthing in jquery for when the active tab is changed?

i want to call a javascript function when the active tab is changed.

i've tried this but dosent work:

```
<script>

$('#feedtab [data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e)
{
    alert('test');
})


</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Straight out of [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

There are two events that get fired
show.bs.tab & shown.bs.tab as their name implies one gets fired before the new content is shown, the other one right after.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  //e.target -> activated tab
  //e.relatedTarget -> previous tab
});
```

Comment: check your console and see if you are getting any javascript error. if so, please post it here.